# Нечеткий текст - высоты шрифта?

Tags: шрифты, дизайн

Создал на скорую руку логотипчик, но шрифт выходит нечетким. Я думаю это из-за того, что я увеличиваю показатель высоты шрифта. Может кто-то сталкивался с похожим шрифтом? Скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Вот лого - [image]
<sub>(источник: [fishing-trade.com](http://fishing-trade.com/image/data/logo.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте векторные редакторы и у вас не будет проблем - все шрифты будут четкие и конкретные.

Попробуйте сondenced-варианты стандартных шрифтов. То же банальный Arial Narrow, Myriad Pro. Можно и обычные шрифты растянуть - но нарушаться пропорции штрихов, а это не всегда подходит.

Попробуйте поискать именно нужный вам шрифт на [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: Благодарю = )